# Counting the number of lines of code that have been commented out

Tags: software-development

I use [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) to count blank lines, comment lines, and physical lines of source code in many programming languages:

[image]

However, in some projects, a fair amount of comment lines are in fact lines of codes that have been commented, e.g. in:

```
  static void findSystem(){
    Config.load();
    List<Question> lQuestions = Question.loadAllValidWithEquations();
    for(Question question : lQuestions){
      //System.out.println(question.ct);
      String sSystem = "(-m*a)+(-n*b)+c = 0\n(-m*b)+(-n*a)+d = 0\n";
      if(question.ct.mt.toString().equals(sSystem)){
        System.out.println("Found it-" + question.iIndex + ":" 
                           + question.ct.mt);
      }
    }
  }
```

the line `//System.out.println(question.ct);` is a line of code that has been commented out: I really don't want to count it as a comment line, since generally speaking having a high amount of true comment lines is good while having a high amount of lines of codes that has been commented out is bad. To make things worse, it's not uncommon to see not just one isolated such commented line of code, but a pack of 10, 100 or even more commented lines of code in a row, which totally fools my code audit statistics.

I am therefore looking for a program that can count the number of lines of codes that have been commented out. If possible, it should take a folder as input and go through all its files (,including subfolders). Ideally, free, work with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate, and support Java/Python/C++ (the more languages, the better).

Comment: I would imagine this would require a tool that you either a) write yourself or b) can customize to your heart's content.  A well written `grep` script could do the job—but it likely can't be intelligent enough on its own to handle multi-language projects like `cloc` seems to be able to do.

Comment: as a side comment - your statement "generally speaking having a high amount of true comment lines is good" is subjective.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki For sure it is debatable. I tried to nuance with "generally speaking" as having too many comments is less common than not enough :) Beyond the mere comment line counting, it's another story to assess the comment quality.

Comment: Would you count a commented line found in Java, coded in COBOL, as such a line? How do you suppose such a tool would decide that a comment is really a statement from the langauge?  What if the line was incomplete? syntactically malformed (e.g., the "if" part of if-then-else)? So syntactically malformed, one might mistake it for a non-code source line?